# Taking pictures periodically while streaming a webcam

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video-streaming, webcam

I want to take pictures with my webcam periodically, i.e., at every 5 seconds, while streaming the video to the browser. How can I do that in Python, using preferably Flask and OpenCV?

Comment: don't write this yourself, use tools like ``motion``

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it is very easy to use your webcam with [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html).

E.g.

```
import time
from VideoCapture import Device
webCam = Device()
name = 1
while(True): # Take pictures forever
    webCam.saveSnapshot(name + '.jpg') # Take picture
    time.sleep(5) # Wait 5 seconds
    name = name+1 # We don't want to write over the same image every time
```

On Linux, it's [a bit more complicated](http://www.jperla.com/blog/post/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux), but it's still the same principle.

However, If you would like to do this without delays, this might work better:

```
import time
from VideoCapture import Device
webCam = Device()
name = 1
while(True): #Take pictures forever
    webCam.saveSnapshot(name + '.jpg') #Take picture
    start = time.time()
    while not (time.time() - start > 50):
        pass
    name = name+1 #We don't want to write over the same image every time
```

Comment: the problem with using time.sleep is that it stops the streaming. I want both streaming and snapshot. I looked to threading.Timer, but I got confused

Comment: You can do this:`start = time.time() while not (time.time() - start >5): pass` See above, I edited my answer

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark my answer as correct. However, if you still need clarification, please state so in the comments.

Comment: I solved the problem differently, by counting frames instead of counting time, and by using an if statement, like here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html